# HTML5: Text area placeholder ::after content css not working in Mozilla and IE

Tags: css, html

I have a problem with Text area placeholder. I need to display my place holder as 2 lines in my project. I am using placeholder::after css for display place holder as two lines. But Mozilla and IE not supporting placeholder::after css for text area. How can I solve this problem. I need separate style for each line placeholder. Some one are saying after and before will not work for text area. So please help me to resolve this.

Google Chrome is working fine .

See Fiddle HERE...[PLACEHOLDER FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Rayudu/ueydf78u/2/)

```css
textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder{
  text-align:center;
  font-size:34px;
  line-height:35px;
 }
 textarea:-moz-placeholder{
  text-align:center;
  font-size:34px;
  line-height:35px;
 }
    textarea::-moz-placeholder{
  text-align:center;
  font-size:34px;
  line-height:35px;
 }
 textarea:-ms-input-placeholder{
  text-align:center;
  font-size:34px;
  line-height:35px;
 }
 textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder::after{
  display: block;
  text-align:center;
  content:"For example, when you last spoke to your customer";
  font-size:20px;
  line-height:20px;
 }
    textarea:-moz-placeholder:after{
  display: block;
  text-align:center;
  content:"For example, when you last spoke to your customer";
  font-size:20px;
  line-height:20px;
 }
 textarea::-moz-placeholder::after{
  display: block;
  text-align:center;
  content:"For example, when you last spoke to your customer";
  font-size:20px;
  line-height:20px;
 }
 textarea:-ms-input-placeholder::after{
  display: block;
  text-align:center;
  content:"For example, when you last spoke to your customer";
  font-size:30px;
  line-height:20px;
 }
```

```html
<textarea  maxlength="25000" style="margin-bottom: 0px; height: 70px; width: 99%;" placeholder="Start Typing here..." ></textarea>
```

Comment: As i know you can not use pure css for multi-line placeholder for all browser support. I have one trick using jquery which you can use. check: http://jsfiddle.net/pdXRx/616/

Comment: @ketan Thanks for this. My problem is I need separate styles for second line placeholder. Please help me to resolve.

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty certain that multi-style placeholders will not work cross-browser or cross-platform as they are all device dependant input elements.  CSS3 support is limited to only a few properties and the pseudo before/after is not one of them.  This post lists the supported properties:  [styling the html5 placeholder](http://blog.ajcw.com/2011/02/styling-the-html5-placeholder/)

Possible alternatives might be to place something (div) behind the text area and make the text-area slightly transparent, until clicked on or to use an image for the placeholder.  Both nasty I know.

Comment: Thanks for idea. I will implement same like your idea.